# Android ListView Adapter not working correctly

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've been attempting to upgrade an old app I made in college, including adding a listview to show data from Last.FM. The idea is having a main text with subtext under it, but the adapter I put together just isn't working. I've tried a good number of options, and the most recent is giving me a "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" error, a previous try got a "Cannot cast Activity to Application" error.

Relevant code sections:

Main Activity adapter section:

```
ListView lv;

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.summarylayout);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemList);                 //Listview name

            artistAdapter = new itemAdapter(getApplicationContext(),            //Changed from ArrayAdapter<Item>
                    R.layout.custom_listview,                        //R.layout.custom_listview if itemAdapter works
                    result.toArray(new Item[] {}));


            lv.setAdapter(artistAdapter);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new MyOIListener());

            Button closeButton = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tracks = false;
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

The custom Adapter itself (Commented sections are previous attempts):

```
public class itemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Item data[] = null;


public itemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Item[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
   // ItemHolder holder = null;
    Item rowIn = new Item();
    TextView main;
    TextView sub;

    if(row == null)
    {
        //LayoutInflater inflater = ((Application)context).getLayoutInflater();
        //row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        //row = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        //holder = new ItemHolder();
        //rowIn = new Item();
    }
    else
    {
        rowIn = (Item) row.getTag();
    }

    main = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    sub = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.subText);

    row.setTag(rowIn);

    Item temp = data[position];
    main.setText(temp.getTitle());
    sub.setText(temp.getExtra());

    return row;
}

   /* static class ItemHolder
{
    TextView mainText;
    TextView subText;
}*/

}
```

The "Item" class is simply a holder for text/URLs parsed from the Last.FM api request.

I realize this is a question asked often, but 3 days of attempts and searching hasn't helped me out much. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passnig the `applicationContext` to your adapter. Pass your `Activity` by:

```
  artistAdapter = new itemAdapter(MainActivity.this,            //Changed from ArrayAdapter<Item>
                R.layout.custom_listview,                        //R.layout.custom_listview if itemAdapter works
                result.toArray(new Item[] {}));
```

Comment: Hey, this did it! I couldn't for the life of me figure out the relationship between the two. If you don't mind, whats the issue with getApplicationContext() vs MainActivity.this?

Comment: Both are instances from `Context`, but the app context regards the application lifecycle and the activity's regards the activity's. One doesn't have access to the same properties the other does. And as @GuillermoMerino said, you should o back using the view holder pattern :)

Comment: I likely will now that I know the issue was with the MainActivity section and not the adapter itself. I tried the holder pattern a couple times but swapped when I couldn't get it working either to calling directly to the items themselves

Answer (score 0):

Your getView method was wrong, actually you will face a null variable there when getting the data from the tag.

This one should work for you, it is using [ViewHolder Pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

```
public class itemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Item data[] = null;


    public itemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Item[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //LayoutInflater inflater = ((Application)context).getLayoutInflater();
            //row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            //row = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) this.context).getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ItemHolder();

            holder.mainText = row.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            holder.subText = row.findViewById(R.id.subText);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Item temp = data[position];

        if(temp != null) {
            holder.mainText.setText(temp.getTitle());
            holder.subText.setText(temp.getExtra());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ItemHolder {
        TextView mainText;
        TextView subText;
    }

}
```

And as @vinitius said, pass your Activity context to the adapter.